# Scaling SARIMA to forecast on thousands of series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, large-data

Currently, I am building out different models for forecasting. SARIMA usually does a great job with the series I am forecasting. Currently, I only have ~100 series to forecast (each series is between 770 and 500 days). I have the parameters being chosen through a grid search separately for each series. I will need to scale this and model ~10000 series. I am quickly realizing this is not going to scale very well because the grid search can take up to 2 minutes. It already take about an hour and a half to produce these forecasts.

My questions are:

1. Is there a method to apply SARIMA to thousands of series if not more?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, is there methods that can account for different parameters like I mentioned above?
3. This is not mentioned above but I would also be interested in trying other methods such as Exponential Smoothing. So if there are methods in the same manner that would be great to know about.

Also, any resources such as books, papers, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you archive the models and then simply create an updated forecast after new observations are observed, this is a very effective way of dealing with tons of time series. You can then rotate new model development (and storage) for specified subsets ..e.g. the state of New York .